# Unable to sync Active Campaign form to Salesforce Lead Field

Tags: salesforce, zapier

I am using Zaiper to integration Active Campaign Contact and Salessforce Lead. I  have multiple form in active campaign. can you please suggest how to populate form name to salesforce lead field.

Thanks.

Comment: I would write into support@zapier.com for help, as this isn't really a code question

Answer (score 0):

This question requires more detail and is not a code related question.

There are plenty of Zapier *Zaps* that can create Salesforce Leads.

Example:

https://zapier.com/apps/activecampaign/integrations/salesforce/11548/add-new-activecampaign-contacts-to-salesforce-as-leads

There is also a *Zap* that can turn Salesforce Leads into Active Campaign Contacts:

https://zapier.com/apps/activecampaign/integrations/salesforce/11560/add-new-salesforce-leads-to-activecampaign-or-update-contacts